# Attempting to send email with SMTP class (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email using the C# SmtpClient class. The "catch" block gets executed after it attempts to "send" the message. When I go to look at the exception, the InnerException says "Unable to connect to the remote server" and the message says "Failure sending mail". The StatusCode is "General failure".

Am I missing certain credentials? Do I need to set some more fields to the instance of the SmtpClient or MailMessage?

Here is the code:

```
 private void sendEmail(string recepientEmailAddress) {
        string subjectEmail = "Subject Email";
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@email.com");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("example@example.com");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = subjectEmail;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "Body example";

        try
        {
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"].ToString());
            sc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            sc.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helpers.ErrorLogger.ProcessError(e.Message, e.StackTrace, "RegistrationController", "SendEmail");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems that the `MailServer` specified in the `AppSettings` is not valid.

Comment: missing username and password dude on which email you try to  send from

Comment: @AsafShazar what's a way to attach the user and password to the email I am sending from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void sendEmail(string recepientEmailAddress) {
        string subjectEmail = "Subject Email";
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@email.com");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("example@example.com");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = subjectEmail;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "Body example";

        try
        {
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"].ToString());
            sc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Host="smtp.gmail.com"
            sc.port = 587;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            sc.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helpers.ErrorLogger.ProcessError(e.Message, e.StackTrace, "RegistrationController", "SendEmail");
        }
    }
```

adding port(gmail:587)

adding host(smtp.gmail.com

if that not working try add User name and password
change from

```
sc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

TO

```
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The email I am sending "from" is outlook. So would " sc.Host=smtp.outlook.com" work instead?

Comment: @tonyleMill What do you mean you're sending from Outlook? Unless your site is hosted on outlook.com, don't send it from outlook.com.

Comment: @mason I am just trying to understand why the host and port have "gmail" on them.

Comment: you try to send email in your company? @tonyleMill

anyway the outlook is connectiong to mailbox server/Cas server(if you work with exchange), in gmail because you need authentication of user and pass so that why i added user and pass,
if in you company you work inside mail such as exchange servers you can do 2 things 


1) use windows intergration that will use the user certification in mail
2) use NetworkCredential with the user name and password of your windows user

Comment: I ended up getting it work in another way, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool Send()
    {
        try
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("xyz@example.com");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("xyziahd@example.com");
            const string subject = "subjects";
            const string userName = "serverCredentail";
            const string Password = "serverpassword";
            const string body = "Body";
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "servernameexample.com",
                Port = 25,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, Password)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This Code should work I just tested it.